# ¿Cómo regreso un valor de una función que use jsdom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs, mochajs

Estoy usando jsdom junto con jQuery, y funciona bien para buscar el dato que quiero en una página, pero para poder hacerle pruebas quiero meterlo en un método.

### Problema

Como jsdom funciona con llamadas asíncronas, si usara un `return` regresaría undefined antes de que terminara de *scrapear*.

### ¿Qué he intentado?

Basado en [una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9419416/4585308) del SOen, decidí usar el patrón de diseño denominado *callback*.

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom/lib/old-api.js");

function get_member_since(callback) {
    jsdom.env({
        url: "https://www.codewars.com/users/Javatlacati",
        scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
        done: function(err, window) {
            var $ = window.$;

            var result = $(".flex-box > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1)").first().text().split(':')[1];
            console.log(result);
            callback(result);
        }
    });

}
```

Pero a pesar de ello mi prueba unitaria no está funcionando.

Código de prueba que uso de momento(ya que lo adapté para el callback):

```
describe("Solution", function() {
    it("should test for something", function() {
        Test.assertEquals(get_member_since(function(result) {
            return result;
        }), "April 2015", "Wrong year");
    });
});
```

lo que me da el mensaje de error:

> Wrong year - Expected: 'April 2015', instead got: undefined

Lo curiosos es que si le pongo al final de mi código

```
console.log(get_member_since(function(result) {
            return result;
        }));
```

funciona y me imprime dos veces el resultado.

Comment: que framework estas utilizando para las pruebas?

Comment: principalmente mocha y chai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias reescribir el test de la siguiente forma:

```
describe("Solution", function() {
    it("should test for something", function(done) {
        get_member_since(function(result) {
            Test.assertEquals(result, "April 2015", "Wrong year");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Segun la [documentacion](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) de mocha, un test asincrono puede recibir un parametro callback (`done`) en `it` y el framework esperará que este se llame para finalizar el test.

Comment: Fantástico! me faltaba el done :D